# initializationError when try to use @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

Tags: java, spring, maven

I try to import in `Intellij IDEA` an existing project. All the dependencies are resolved and project build is successful. When I try to execute project I got following error message:

> Could not initialize class
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner

Following code didn't help me to solve this, I found it in another similar question.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <configuration>
            <junitArtifactName>junit:junit:4.12</junitArtifactName>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Version numbers:

```
Spring 4.3.3

Junit 4.12
```

Comment: Can you add some more output?

Comment: @kewne : That is all, it ends with these lines:
_false
Process finished with exit code 0_

Comment: How about running the maven build or manually running a test, does that work?

Comment: By "execute project" you mean running your tests from Intellij? Are junit and spring-test dependencies declared in maven test scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more details (e.g. sample project on github) it might be difficult for us to find a root cause.

It seems you are overriding junit version somewhere in your pom.
As stated in documentation [SpringRunner](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringRunner.html)
requires junit 4.12 or higher.

There was a similar bug reported for spring boot project:
[Spring Boot Issue 5695](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5695)

You can use tools like mvn dependency:tree to find out actual project dependencies.